# Export Volume Cube to vdb format

Tags: export

Is it possible to export a volume cube output in a geometry node setup to a VDB file (ideally as a sequence)? I know that it is possible to export fluid simulations and also saw that there exists a unofficial plugin that exports shader volumes to VDB but that's only for shaders.